# C# Call Different Functions in Core Function

Tags: c#

In C#, How can I simplify `GetData1()` and `GetData2()` to one line function only?
Please see comments in `GetData1` and `GetData2`, originally I have two write 3 lines in each function, but would like to use `GetDataCore` to simplify it.

```
    public IEnumerable<int> GetDataCore(function passInFunction)
    {
        // many other steps
        foreach (var sensor in sensors)
        {
            yield return sensor.passInFunction();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetData1()
    {
        // many other steps
        // TODO: use something like 
        // return GetDataCore(GetData1);
        foreach (var sensor in sensors)
        {
            yield return sensor.GetData1();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetData2()
    {
        // many other steps
        // TODO: use something like 
        // return GetDataCore(GetData1);
        foreach (var sensor in sensors)
        {
            yield return sensor.GetData2();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write your own method to project all of the items in a sequence using a selector passed as a delegate.  LINQ created such a method for you, called `Select`:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetData1() {
    return sensors.Select(sensor => sensor.GetData1());
}
```

But, to answer your question anyway, if `function` was a `Func<Sensor, int>`, then you could pass in a method that takes a sensor and transforms it into an integer, which you could do in each of your `GetDataX` methods, most likely using a lambada, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. Seems only lamda can do this.